# C#: How to load assembly from GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac

I have "mycomp.myassembly.dll" in GAC but Load and LoadFrom throws file not found exception and LoadWithPartialName returns null. I'm doing the following:

```
    AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName();
    name.Name = "mycomp.myassembly.dll";

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(name);
```

fails with FileNotFound for mycomp.myassembly.dll file, and

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("mycomp.myassembly.dll");
```

fails with exactly the same message.

I double checked that assembly is in GAC (and even did gacutil /if for it again) and it does work in all other cases, I just unable to load it myself.

What am I doing wrong here?
Do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried to supply assembly name without an extension ".dll"?
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("mycomp.myassembly");

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't help either

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried using the fully qualified assembly name? (e.g. `"ycomp.myassembly.dll, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3"`)

Comment: Double quotes are important guys.

Comment: To be complete... are you using the full name because there is no way to provide the public key when using `Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName {...})`?

Answer (score 1):

try simply [loading with the full name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx)

```
 // You must supply a valid fully qualified assembly name.            
        Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
            ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```

I can usually load without the version, culture and public key.

Comment: I think the public key would be needed, without the public key it's treated as an entirely different assembly. All assemblies in the GAC will have a public key.

Comment: you are right. i was brain farting and thinking of loading local assemblies