# How to add a reference to an assembly which is registered in the GAC at runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, versioning, gac

How to add a reference to an assembly which is registered in the GAC at runtime?

I'd like to reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll from the Gac depending on the Run Time Server and its GAC rather than Build Server and Build Time.

But Add Reference dialog adds the build server gac version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279341/c-how-to-load-assembly-from-gac

Comment: That's an incredibly bad idea, turning DLL Hell from a runtime problem into a build problem makes it a hundred times worse.